# BASH - comparing two catalogues, -r --exclude will not do

Tags: bash, comparison, diff

I want to compare two catalogues. They look like this:

```
Catalogue1    Catalogue 2
file1.txt     file1.txt
file2.txt     file2.txt
file3.txt     file3.txt
file4.txt     file4.txt
file5.txt     file5.txt
file6.txt     file6.txt
files.zip     files.zip
```

I just want to have the *.txt files compared, but the command

```
diff -r --exclude=".zip" $CURRENT_BUILD_DIR $PREVIOUS_BUILD_DIR >> $DIFF_DIR/DIFF.TXT
```

is of no use here. The effect of this command looks like this

```
Files /home/blah/workspace/Catalogue1/files.zip and /home/blah/workspace/Catalogue2/files.zip are different. // not sure about that, translated it from German.

diff -r '--exclude=.zip' /home/blah/workspace/Catalogue1/file1.TXT /home/blah/workspace/Catalogue2/file1.TXT
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
```

Why is diff still trying to compare the zip files even with the exclude option?

Comment: You have not ordered to `diff` command to exclude the ZIP files but ONLY the file whose names are `.zip`. To exclude any ZIP file you must use `--exclude="*.zip"`. The `exclude` options admits a filename pattern; not a filename extension pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff -r --exclude="*.zip" "$CURRENT_BUILD_DIR" "$PREVIOUS_BUILD_DIR" >> "$DIFF_DIR"/DIFF.TXT`

Comment: some kind of explanation would help to understand what was the problem!